# Xamarin Forms DatePicker Not binding with viewmodel property in UWP?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

My DatePicker is not binding with my viewmodel property in UWP whereas its working in android and ios.

My view:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="StartDate" Date="{Binding StartDate, Mode=TwoWay}" Opacity="0.45" HeightRequest="50" Focused="OnScreenTapped" />
```

ViewModel:

```
private DateTime? _startDate; 

public DateTime? StartDate
 {

    get
    {
       return _startDate;
    }
    set
    {
       _startDate = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("StartDate");
    }
 }
```

I initailaised my date with `StartDate = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01);` but it shows current date only......
Also when I change the date in date picker it does not change in viewmodel....

Any help is appreciated...Thanks

Comment: I think, that problem is in nullable property on view model. [This topic](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20028/datepicker-possible-to-bind-to-nullable-date-value) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce your issue, But `DatePicker` binding works in my side. You could refer to the following code  to check if you have missed some key procedure.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinDatePickerTest"
             x:Class="XamarinDatePickerTest.MainPage"
             xmlns:ViewMode ="clr-namespace:XamarinDatePickerTest.ViewModel"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
             >
   <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <ViewMode:MainPageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <StackLayout>
        <DatePicker VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Date="{Binding Datetime}">
            <DatePicker.Format>yyyy-MM-dd</DatePicker.Format>
            <DatePicker.MinimumDate>
                <sys:DateTime x:FactoryMethod="Parse">
                    <x:Arguments>
                        <x:String>Jan 1 2000</x:String>
                    </x:Arguments>
                </sys:DateTime>
            </DatePicker.MinimumDate>
        </DatePicker>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime? _datetime;

    public DateTime? Datetime
    {
        get => _datetime;

        set
        {
            _datetime = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        this.Datetime = new DateTime(2011, 12, 18);
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

And I have uploaded the [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/XamarinDatePickerTest.git) to github, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Just experienced the same issue. My problem was the nullable date. By default, the DatePicker doesn't allow nullable dates (defaults to todays date), but you can add a custom control to get it to work.